# CSS: Make height of an inner div 100%, when parent is already 100%

Tags: css, html

I have tried on my own for such a long time and all the posts I have read and googled so far have not helped me, so I hope one of you guys can give me a hint:

I have a Layout consisting of a header, a footer, and a content. This layout streches over the whole page in height (which has already taken me a while to figure out). So far, so good. But now I want to stretch the `content-div` as far down as possible, down to the beginning of the footer. No matter what I do, it does not work, it either stays the length of the text in it, or it becomes the size of the whole window, hiding the footer and generating a scrollbar.
I read about a solution making it `position:absolute`, but I don't want that.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/N9Gjf/1/

You would really help me out!

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%
    overflow: hidden;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
}   

#footer {
    background-color: silver;
    height:1.5em;
    width:800px;
    margin: -1.5em auto;
}

#header {
    background-color: orange;
    height:100px;
}

#content {
    background-color: limegreen;
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    INHALT  
    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your css near `height:100%`. Add a semicolon and perhaps your problem resolves itself.

Comment: Not quite, he needs to add the height to the content too.

Comment: Just had another look at the code, adding the missing `;` _appears_ to fix everything but it does not!

Comment: Of course it doesn't. He has no height set on the content. I answered this nearly 5 minutes ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/CprV7/

You had a missing semi-colon after height in the wrapper. You want to set the height and min-height of the content to 100% as well.

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
width:800px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
background-color:lightblue;
}

#content {
background-color: limegreen;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to set `min-height` and `height`? Surely just `min-height` would suffice?

Comment: Old habit for compatibility, probably completely unnecessary now but it still just sticks with me lol

Comment: WHAT.THE.HELL!
I did have something there before in the content definition but erased it because it didn't work. And I definitely had height:100% there as well. Maybe some of there other things inside interfered with it, because it made the green content box really a 100% of the whole window high as explained. Thanks so much thought! This has really bothered me for an entire day. Thanks to all the other helpers as well! I appreciate it!

Comment: What to do if #content has a lot of content? it will drop down above or beneath the footer http://jsfiddle.net/N9Gjf/376/ , breaking the layout

Answer (score 2):

I think relative-absolute positioning is the best solution (I admit I am unable to find a way to make the heights sum up to 100%). Here is what you need to do:

[**Demo #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/N9Gjf/4/)

1. Make the wrapper position relative
2. Put all divs inside the wrapper
3. Use absolute positioning to position and size content and footer; use one of the following:

   1. Do not specify `height` of the div; specify `top` and `bottom`
   2. Specify either `top` or `bottom` but not both; specify `height`

Alternate method is to use negative margins. This could be a brain twister but once you grasp the idea it becomes mush simpler than positioning. Here is what you need to do:

[**Demo #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/N9Gjf/7/)

1. Assign heights to header and footer
2. Assign 100% height to content
3. Use negative margins on content so that (i) content pushes itself over the header (ii) pulls footer over itself
4. Use z-index positioning to bring header in "front" of content
5. Use a padding div to push the stuff inside the content div below the header

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%; /*missed the semicolon here*/
    overflow: hidden;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:lightblue; position:relative
}
```

Now it works **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Gjf/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

You forgot to put a `;` at the end of `height:100%`.

Try it and you will see that it will work